# R for loop optimization

Tags: r, for-loop

The panel data I have is structured this way:

```
id   year   count
1    2000   5
1    2001   6
1    2002   1
2    2000   3
2    2001   4
2    2002   0
.
.
.
```

I have a the coordinates for each "id" stored in "coords". The following are also assigned:

```
library(lctools)
bw<-10
wt<-'Binary'
```

Here's the actual question now: I would like to write a loop that'll run through each year and calculates the Spatial Gini coefficient for each year using the "count" variable. Here's how I've done it and it works fine:

```
## create subsets of data for each year
for(year in 2000:2002)
{
name1 <- paste("data",year,sep="")  
assign(name1, mydata[which(mydata$year==year),] )
}

## extract the count variable for each year
filenames <- c("data2000","data2001","data2002")
for (filename in filenames) {
  i <- get(filename)
  name2 <- paste("count",filename,sep="")
  assign(name2,i$count)
}

## calculate spatial gini for each year
counts <- c("countdata2000","gpcountdata2001","gpcountdata2002")
for(j in counts)
{
  name3 <- paste("spGini",j,sep="")
  countvar<-get(j)
  assign(name3,spGini(coords, bw, countvar, wt))
}
```

This to me feels like a very inefficient way of coding this. Can anyone please help me optimize it?

Edit: coords

```
> head(coords)
     longitude latitude
[1,] -74.55368 45.18756
[2,] -74.56386 45.05547
[3,] -74.93253 45.06439
```

Sample output for 2 iterations:

```
      Gini     gwGini     nsGini 
0.90895332 0.01149272 0.89746060 
      Gini     gwGini     nsGini 
0.90828759 0.01145735 0.89683025
```

Comment: Why all the assignments? This seems like a job for `split/lapply','data.table' or 'dplyr'.

Comment: This is un-R like code - can you share a little of coords, and your expected output?

Comment: don't put info in comments, edit your question

Comment: Does `spGini(coords, bw, mydata[mydata$year==2000,"count"], wt)` do one year? Your loops just seem to be heavy ways of subsetting rows and getting one column. If I'm right then you just write a loop over years and put that where i've got 2000 and store in a list...

Comment: I'm repeating myself here from another question, but loops are generally not the anser in R, unless they are. In this case, they are not.

Comment: That's what I tried initially and the error was: "Error in data.frame(x, DNeighbour = Dij[, m]) : arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 574"  and 574 is the number of unique id counts.

Comment: Does `lapply(split(dat,dat$year),function(x){spGini(coords, bw, x$count, wt)})` do what you want?

Comment: Yes! I was told I should get into the "apply" world to be able to fully utilize R but I've been postponing it. Seems like it's finally caught up with me. Thank you very much Heroka.

Comment: Code optimization questions should be asked on CodeReview rather than StackOverflow http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I read your code right, then the idiomatic way to do it may be as simple as:

```
myGinis = lapply(2000:2004, function(y){ 
  spGini(coords, bw, mydata[mydata$year==y,"count"], wt)
}
```

Then the results are in `myGinis[[1]]` for 2000, `myGinis[[2]]` for 2001 and so on.